# How to test goodness of fit for AFT Survival Models?

Tags: regression, survival

I am testing a few survival models in the parametric family and would like to test the goodness of fit of the models to the data I have. Which tests would be useful and is it even necessary to carry out the GOF test if the idea is to use the model for predictions for time to event?

Is it enough to compare the predicted against observed values and compare the variances observed between each type of distribution to get the best model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Akeike Information Criterion to compare fit between models. AIC is a valid approach as long as you keep the sample exactly the same for all models tested. The lower the AIC, the better the model. While predictions from parametric models can be simpler to export, the Cox model can fit a range of irregular shapes. Don’t violate assumptions of the various models in a quest to achieve better fit.

Comment: thanks, i tried to implemet a cox model initially but the problem i had with this model is there is no option to provide predicted time to event and it gives a hazard rate. parametric models are able to provide estimates in terms of  time to event values.

Comment: If this response answers your question, please accept the answer.